# How Can my app know if android device has received a new message

Tags: javascript, react-native, sms

I am new to React-Naive and trying to build an app that sends message through app using [react-native-get-sms-android](https://github.com/briankabiro/react-native-get-sms-android#readme).

I am able to **send** and **read** SMS from inbox but there is no **Event** in the package to know if a new sms has been received.

Is there any **Event** or **API** in **react native** for this?
I think I will have to use **polling** to check if a new sms has arrived.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either create your own native module or use `react-native-android-sms-listener` to listen for the new messages similar to **Whatsapp**.

Manual Installation is provided in the [docs](https://github.com/CentaurWarchief/react-native-android-sms-listener#manual-installation)

### Usage

import SmsListener from 'react-native-android-sms-listener'

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.subscription = SmsListener.addListener(message => {
    console.info(message)
  })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.subscription.remove()
}
```

where the contents are in the format

```
{
  originatingAddress: string,
  body: string
}
```

Also make sure that you need specific permissions to read SMS for android, check the permissions docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid)

Comment: This is working perfectly fine I have just got a tiny problem . My reply is large so it comes in 2 parts i.e 2 body and I am able to display only 1 where as I want both. What should I do to display both body elements.

Comment: I have tried adding delay and then reading the reply but i still get only one body element

Comment: Not sure about if the library handles multipart sms, or you need to add some modifications to it.

Comment: Does this package can listen incoming message if app is in background ? I want to use for such case.